# Create Temporary Views

Tags: apex, lightning-aura-components, metadata-api, list-view, console

I'm looking at using the Lightning Sales Console for my users, but I also want to give them the ability to quickly create a List from a whim and work from that. Creating Lists in Salesforce is a bit of a pain, so my goal is to create a Lightning Component that is invoked from a Global Action that shows a modal popup, and provides a defined subset of filters (vs every possible choice like the normal View builder) that they can save as a new list, then refreshes the sales console with the just created View.

I believe this will have to be done via the Metadata API as there is no apex documentation on the subject.

Furthermore, I don't want to clog up the Views on my object with a bunch of one use Views. So i'd like to run a cron job at the end of each day that wipes that day's created Views.

I'd like to get opinions and insight from anyone that has attempted something like this or better yet, examples of how it has been done.

Comment: Have you tried anything yet? It sounds like bringing List Views into the mix will only serve to make this problem more complicated, not less.

Comment: @AdrianLarson Have not tried anything yet, no. In the planning stage, but was hoping to get more insight here (maybe not the best idea). Views are required because that is the only way it is supported by Console Apps

Comment: But once you are already working in a Lightning Component it seems like you have more flexibility, no?